# Time since a isodate timestamp in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

Yes, this should be a programming 101 type problem, but I seem to have taken myself down one rabbit hole after another.

I have a data object that has a timestamp in iso format.  So it looks like this: "2013-09-19T21:37:04Z"

I need to determine if that timestamp is less than 30 minutes in the past.

I have tried things like this:

```
timeStamp="2013-09-19T21:37:04Z"
now=datetime.datetime.now()
age=now-timeStamp
if age < (30*60)
    doStuff()
```

Plus a bunch of variants.  But I think I am working WAY to hard at a simple task.

How can I tell if that timestamp is more than 30 minutes old?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert timeStamp to a datetime object first.

```
timeStamp="2013-09-19T21:37:04Z"
timeStamp_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeStamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
age = now - timeStamp_dt
if age < datetime.timedelta(minutes=30):
    doStuff()
```

This would not take timezone into account. Maybe it can be improved.

Comment: I can work with that.  datetime.datetime.utcnow() gives the current zulu time.

Comment: is ...strptime portable?

Comment: But this still seems a bit too complex an answer to a simple question.

Comment: @SkipHuffman, you're starting with a string - a one-line conversion doesn't seem complicated to me. If you want the `age` in seconds directly you can make `age = (now - timeStamp_dt).total_seconds()`.

Comment: It is not a generic string it is an iso8601 datestamp.  I should not have to hand code parsing a standard data type.  The isodate module seems to partially handle this, but seems to lose the timezone (zulu) information.

Comment: @SkipHuffman, the timezone handling in the built-in `datetime` module is extremely deficient. Try the [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) or [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) modules for something better.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [time.clock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock).

```
start = time.clock()
#... some steps
if time.clock() - start < 30 * 60:
    doStuff()
```

Since you need to use the datetime; this one should work:

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
#...some steps
if ((datetime.now() - start).seconds < 30 * 60:
    doStuff()
```

Comment: I need to use the timestamp from the data object.